# Can I control the font size in the margins of a StyledTextCtrl?

Tags: python, wxpython

I've slightly reduced the font size of my [StyledTextCtrl](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl-class.html), but it didn't affect the font size in the margins of the text control, namely the line number font:

[image: Example]

**Is there any way to control the font size in the margins?**

---

For those interested, here is my subclass:

```
class CustomTextCtrl(StyledTextCtrl):
    """A `StyledTextCtrl` subclass with custom settings."""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        StyledTextCtrl.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # Set the highlight color to the system highlight color.
        highlight_color = wx.SystemSettings.GetColour(wx.SYS_COLOUR_HIGHLIGHT)
        self.SetSelBackground(True, highlight_color)

        # Set the font to a fixed width font.
        font = wx.Font(12, wx.FONTFAMILY_TELETYPE, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL,
                       wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, False, 'Consolas',
                       wx.FONTENCODING_UTF8)
        self.StyleSetFont(0, font)

        # Enable line numbers.
        self.SetMarginType(1, wx.stc.STC_MARGIN_NUMBER)
        self.SetMarginMask(1, 0)
        self.SetMarginWidth(1, 25)

    def SetText(self, text):
        """Override of the `SetText` function to circumvent readonly."""

        readonly = self.GetReadOnly()
        self.SetReadOnly(False)
        StyledTextCtrl.SetText(self, text)
        self.SetReadOnly(readonly)

    def ClearAll(self):
        """Override of the `ClearAll` function to circumvent readonly."""

        readonly = self.GetReadOnly()
        self.SetReadOnly(False)
        StyledTextCtrl.ClearAll(self)
        self.SetReadOnly(readonly)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong style number for StyleSetFont. You probably meant to use:

```
self.StyleSetFont(wx.stc.STC_STYLE_DEFAULT,font)
```

which has a value of 32 not 0. If you want to set the font for the line numbers separately, use:

```
self.StyleSetFont(wx.stc.STC_STYLE_LINENUMBER,font)
```

See [wxStyledTextCtrl - Styling & Style Definition](http://www.yellowbrain.com/stc/styling.html) for more details.

Comment: You are correct. I assumed "style number" meant the index of an array of styles I could manage myself.